# Error while using FastImage with my react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

while integrating FastImage with my react native app I am getting the below error:-

[image]

Code:-

```
import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";
const qmeLogoURL = require('../../assets/splash-screen/logo.png');
 <FastImage
            style={styles.image}
            source={Logo}
        />
```

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "expo": "~38.0.1",
    "expo-av": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~8.2.0",
    "expo-file-system": "^9.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.3.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.10",
    "expo-video-player": "^1.5.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "~0.62.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.33.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0"
  },
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I saw in your **package.json** that you are using expo and **if you are using expo managed workflow you can't use this module, if it is a bare workflow then you can**, have a look at this.

https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/704

This error occurs when you **don't link your native module with your project** so since auto-linking is been introduced in 0.60.0 version of react-native so it should be auto-linked so after installing a native module (react-native-fast-image) you must have to re-install the app again.

**if you are on IOS do this.**

```
cd ios
pod install
```

**and install the app again.**

if you are **on android simply rebuild your project and install the app again**

Comment: I am running the app in the expo ios simulator. But still getting the same error.

Comment: In the expo simulator there is a managed workflow, so you can't run it there.

Comment: I am using expo to run my app. So what can i do now?

Comment: there is two workflows with the expo one is managed and other is bare, you have to identify which one you are using if it is managed then you can't use that library.